# Vaadin 14 @Route annotated views are instantiated before the BeforeEnterListener is called?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I was under the impression that views should not be constructed before the Login event occurs.

I am starting migrating from vaadin 8 straight to vaadin 14 rc4. I am not using CDI yet. Is this a bug or something is not properly configured?
This happens in the beverage UI plain java starter.

The views are thus instantiated twice. Its the second instance the one that gets attached to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin 14 doesn't listen to login events internally. If you want to delay the initialization of views, you can register them dynamically; see more here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/routing/tutorial-router-dynamic-routes.html